# Xamarin Android: update ListFragment's items periodically

Tags: android, xamarin, android-listfragment

here is my code:

```
public class ClientsFragment : ListFragment
{
    List<ClientViewModel> list;
    Timer timer;

    public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        await LoadClientList();
        ListAdapter = new ClientAdapter(Activity, list);

        timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await LoadClientList();
    }

    public async Task LoadClientList()
    {
        list = await ClientViewModel.GetAllClients();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except updating content. I have read, that NotifyDataSetChanged function is needed, but I don't know how to implement that, because every example found on web was connected with Activity or custom ListView, not ListFragment. I don't know if my timer is well-written too. Thanks for help

**EDIT:**

Solution was to use `Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => { ListAdapter = new ClientAdapter(Activity, list); });` in the bottom of `LoadClientList` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you want to reset the content in your fragment, you will need to re-attach your adapter in your scenario.

Ideally you would call `NotifyDataSetChanged` once you do something to the `Adapter` such as `Add()`, `Remove()`, `Insert()`, `Clear()`, etc.

So there's a few ways you can approach this:

1. Simply re-create the Adapter with the new list that contains the updated list.
2. Within your Custom `Adapter`, simply allow yourself to change the `List` inside which might call to re-attach the Adapter or call `NotifyDataSetChanged` using the respective methods above.

Note: You may want to ensure you are calling `NotifyDataSetChanged` on the UI thread.

Comment: When adding `ListAdapter = new ClientAdapter(Activity, list);` at the bottom of `LoadClientList` function i got `Unhandled exception` error. I think that it's the problem with updating GUI from another thread, am I right? How to handle that?

Comment: You should have an entry in your `Application Output` pane which will tell you what the `Unhandled Exception` is. Otherwise you can probably grab it from your `adb logcat`

Comment: Thanks, `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: You'll need to ensure you're updating on the UI Thread via: http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/System.Action/

(You should be able to get the Activity/Context easily from the `OnAttach()` override method)

Comment: Ok I changed it to `Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => { ListAdapter = new ClientAdapter(Activity, list); });` and it works good, but when updating my view is scrolling to the top of list every refresh, do you know how to cope with that?

Comment: I believe that would be another question that you can ask!